# Time vs times confusion

Tags: time

"The Healthy Homes Guarantee Bill had long lead-in times for landlords to get their properties up to code."

Why did the journalist use "times" instead of "time"?

Would it be also correct if it had been written like this: 
The Healthy Homes Guarantee Bill had a long lead-in time for landlords to get their properties up to code

Comment: There were probably many items that needed to be up to code, each with a different lead-in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bill had multiple compliance requirements, with multiple time lines or Due dates. 
The author means to say that all or most of those time lines were long, as opposed to just one of them, and hence the use of a plural "times".